# Difference between CRAM and KnowRob

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi every one,

want to ask what is the difference between CRAM and KnowRob ?!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46340/difference-between-cram-and-knowrob/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CRAM packages provide a high-level executive, KnowRob is a knowledge base. The following paper describes these components: https://ias.in.tum.de/_media/spezial/bib/beetz10cram.pdf

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-22**:
KnowRob is knowledge base about environment map  represented in OWL and object models and semantics related to this objects .. also support processing this knowledge and integration with robot perception ?!

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2012-10-22**:
Yes, KnowRob is a knowledge processing system for robots that, among other kinds of knowledge, also supports the representation of objects. All of this is also described in the documentation and the papers about KnowRob and CRAM.

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-22**:
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CRAM is a set of libraries for implementing cognitive robot behavior, its kernel mainly composed of two parts, one is knowrob , and another is CPL.

CRAM integrates different reasoning mechanisms in an executive written in CPL, when a robot needs to make decisions,  its plan(written in CPL) can query the KnowRob reasoner to infer the knowledge needed for decisions.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-21**:
CPL has nothing to do with planning. The package [cram_language](http://ros.org/wiki/cram_language) provides the CRAM plan language which is a domain specific language for implementing robot executives. It is the core of the CRAM system.

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-21**:
so I have to use CRAM to infer missing component on table, so that robot take the decision to move toward the container where this component is stored ?!

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-10-21**:
@Lorenz:Thanks! I think I maps the "series of robot executives" to "plans" intuitively, but isn't making those decisions be a kind of planning?
@RiskTeam: My answer is a simpler way to get the whole picture, you should refer to the paper moritz posted.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-10-21**:
@RiskTeam: If you want to do the task you mentioned well, I think CRAM is the best system now.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-21**:
@RiskTeam this answer is not correct and sort of misleading. I am the main developer of CRAM and I can say CRAM is not a cognitive model. Instead, it is a set of libraries for implementing cognitive robot behavior by integrating different reasoning mechanisms in an executive written in CPL.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-10-21**:
Thanks for correction!

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-21**:
@Ricky, I suggest you edit your answer to clarify it and make it a correct answer :)

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-22**:
What I understand is that KNOWROB is responsible for Knowledge processing which written in OWL and integrate data from different sources, and make reasoning on it such as infer missing component and CRAM make the robot take the decision to move toward the container. Is this scenario correct ?!

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-10-22**:
Yap, I suggest you to write some applications to fully understand the idea, you can see [www.ros.org/wiki/cram_core/Tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cram_core/Tutorials)

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2012-10-23**:
@Lorenz and Ricky Thanks a Lot ^_^

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-10-23**:
Welcome : )